# How to tackle SAFE_CAST sql function in pyspark

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

We have below query which is working in big query environment.

```
SELECT id,name, SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) as resultvalue from patienttable 
where  SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) > 0
```

I need run that query in spark environment using python.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
df = spark.read.parquet(path)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

df2=spark.sql("""SELECT id,name, SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) as resultvalue from patienttable 
where  SAFE_CAST(value AS FLOAT64) > 0""")
```

As we have put same query which is used in big query in pyspark sql then we are getting below error:

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, `SAFE_CAST` is used to prevent errors from casting.
In Spark SQL, `cast` function will return `null` if the conversion is not possible. And there is no such function `SAFE` in Spark.

Also, you're using `FLOAT64` which is specific to Bigquery too, you should be using just `float`. Try this:

```
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT id, name, CAST(value AS FLOAT) AS resultvalue FROM patienttable WHERE CAST(value AS FLOAT) > 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
new_df = spark.sql("select id, name, cast(value as float) as resultvalue from patienttable WHERE value > 0")
```

If you want a specific decimal point in your data use `decimal(a, b)` instead of `float`.